# Index Error: Tuple Index Out Of Range

Tags: python-3.x

```
for count in range(10,60,10):
    myWidth = 30 - count
    mywidth2 = myWidth + 30
    myCharacter = '#'
    print('{0:>{width}}''{6:<{width2}}'.format(
            myCharacter, width=myWidth, width2=mywidth2))
```

Can you please help me I am new at this and I want to learn why I got this error

### Detailed Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/~compname~/Desktop/Game.py", line 5, in <module>
print('{0:>{width}}''{6:<{width2}}'.format(myCharacter, width = myWidth,  width2 = mywidth2))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Btw im trying to make a christmas tree using formatting and width variables!

Answer (score 0):

The `6` in the format says to use the 7th positional parameter in the format argument list and there is no such argument.  Here is a simplified version of the same error.

```
>>> '{1}'.format(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    '{1}'.format(1)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

With `6` changed to `0` to use the same char again, and brackets added to delimit the output

```
for count in range(10,60,10):
    myWidth = 30 - count
    mywidth2 = myWidth + 30
    myCharacter = '#'
    print('[{0:>{width}}{0:<{width2}}]'.format(
            myCharacter, width=myWidth, width2=mywidth2))
```

one gets

```
[                   ##                                                 ]
[         ##                                       ]
[##                             ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\mypy\tem.py", line 6, in <module>
    myCharacter, width=myWidth, width2=mywidth2))
ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier
```

In other words, a negative width field makes no sense.